# Which element has the focus on handling ng-blur

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to get the activeelement | element with focus when handling the `ng-blur` event. I've tried `window.document.activeElement` but it is always 'body'.

#### Html

```html
<body>
  <div name="element1" ng-blur="$ctrl.onBlur($event)">element1</div>
  <div name="element2" ng-blur="$ctrl.onBlur($event)">element2</div>
</body>
```

#### Typescript

```
public onBlur($event: any): void {
   var value = $event.target.attributes["name"].value;
   // value is the name of the element where the event is triggered
   // but how to get the element to where the focus has gone to?
}
```

---

### Edit

Fixed it using the `$timeout` service.

```
public onBlur($event: any): void {
   this.$timeout(() => {
      if (this.$window.document.activeElement) {
         // do things
      }
   }, 1);
}
```

Comment: 100 is too much. try with 0, 1 or 2 You should get the same result

Comment: Yep, 1 works just as well. Changed my question.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using the $timeout service.

```
public onBlur($event: any): void {
   this.$timeout(() => {
      if (this.$window.document.activeElement) {
         // do things
      }
   }, 1);
}
```